# Cloud Backup Options for HD Attached to Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, backup

I connected an external HD to my Time Capsule and I've relocated my iPhoto and iTunes libraries to this HD.  Time Machine is only backing up my computer's HD and I'd like an offsite backup of the external HD.  I'm looking for recommendations on software services that would work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cloud/online based backups here are a few to consider:

- [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/news.html)
- [Mozy](http://mozy.com/)
- [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com.au/online-backup/)
- [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/?utm_source=Google_Branded&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=text_link&utm_campaign=Branded&gclid=CIKD7MvL4q4CFcVMpgod0TFCWw)

They are all mostly the same - you install their software, pay an annual or monthly fee and your data is constantly backed up to their servers. A few offer more advanced features like mirroring to their servers and another machine.

I've put **Backblaze** at the top because thats what I use at home to backup my photos and music. Its cheap @ $50 per year for unlimited storage. I set it up once and never had to look at it again. Last week I recovered a folder of files through their web-interface, though you can (like most cloud backup companies) order a hard-drive with the contents.

---

Another more DIY solution is using [**AmazonS3**](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) combined with a backup program like [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/). You use S3 for the storage and then setup your backup/sync options in Goodsync. We use this at work to backup important project files. The advantage of this method is you have the same level of control you get when using backup software (timed backups/backups when files are changed/email notifications/advanced file comarison etc)

Here is a good starter [article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008020123070799) for AmazonS3 backups. Its also worth noting that AmazonS3 might end up being more expansive than a regular cloud backup service. You can calculate how much S3 would cost using their [Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html?)